# Wildcard SaaS platform domains, over HTTPS, on Kubernetes

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, cloudflare, cert-manager, gitlab-autodevops

I'm deploying a custom SaaS platform to Kubernetes and my clients get X.myplatform.com domains. So, could be acmecorp.myplatform.com, etc.

Previously, on our old devops setup, we just had an Apache record that was *.myplatform.com and had a wildcard [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) certificate to secure it. However, we're now moving to Kubernetes and I feel a bit stumped on how to handle this.

For further context, we're using [GitLab's Auto DevOps features](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/) for our deployments, though I can work to customize our Ingress or cert-manager installs however necessary.

Any suggestions on how to best achieve this? We use Cloudflare on the network level, but without their Enterprise plan, I can't proxy wildcard subdomains.

Comment: u wanna use lets encrypt with k8s ?

Comment: It seems you've answered your own question. Either go with CF Enterprise plan and use certificates managed by them or reproduce your old setup with K8S and whatever web server you're going to use.